# Binding Buttons' style to ViewModel property in WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm, styles

I have a play button in a AudioRecord View.

Currently it is declered as:

```
<Button Width="72" Height="72" Style="{StaticResource RoundPlay}" 
                DataContext="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=DataContext}"
                cmd:ButtonBaseExtensions.Command="{Binding PlayStopCommand}"
                />
```

When a user clicks the button, a PlayStopCommand in items ViewModel gets executed. I want the button to get its' style set to "RoundStop" whenever the sound is playing.

How can I bind the buttons' Style to a property in my ViewModel (what property type should I use), so that the look of the button is controllable from code?

I have RoundStop style defined, I just need a way to apply it to a button from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the playing state in you viewmodel (Playing/Stopped), and bind Button.Style to that property using a converter. In your converter, return a different style (taken from App.Current.Resources) based on the current state.

**Edit:**

Here's an example of your converter should look like:

```
public class StateStyleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (PlaybackState)value == PlaybackState.Playing ? App.Current.Resources["RoundPlay"] : App.Current.Resources["RoundStop"];
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In this example, PlaybackState is an enum:

```
public enum PlaybackState
{
    Playing,
    Stopped
}
```

Then you should add the state property to your view model (The part where you notify the change depends on the framework you are using for MVVM):

```
private PlaybackState state;
public PlaybackState State
{
    get { return state; }
    set
    {
        state = value;
        RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged("State");
    }
}
```

Declare your converter in XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:StateStyleConverter x:Key="StateStyleConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And finally bind it to the button:

```
<Button Width="72" Height="72" Style="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource StateStyleConverter}}" 
            DataContext="{Binding ElementName=this, Path=DataContext}"
            cmd:ButtonBaseExtensions.Command="{Binding PlayStopCommand}"
            />
```

Comment: Thank you. If you bump into an example, of how this is achieved in a demo project, drop a download like here. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! I edited the question and included an example on how to do this. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ToggleButton` and make the necessary visual changes in the visual states for checked/unchecked.

If you *must* do it the way your question states, then you can define the Style in the resources and then access it in the code-behind from `this.Resources["YourStyleKey"];` Your problem will be getting it from the view to the view model, hence my first suggestion :)

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean "Your problem will be getting it from the view to the view model".

Comment: I simply meant that the benefits of separating view and view model are going to break down if you start handing the view over to the view model so that you can get to the Resources. I meant "problem" in the idealistic pattern-adherence sense :)

Comment: I get it. Thank you. Well, ToggleButton is a different control. I have a complex button template defined, and I an not sure I won't have to redifine at least some parts of it, if I switch to ToggleButton. I have seen such things as 'States' in Blend, I will try to "cook" something with them.